# Error in retriving data by id in Laravel i 5.2

Tags: mysql, routes, laravel-5

I am trying to retrieve data from my database, show data for a specific Id.
here Is my Database structure.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ23h.png)

Here Is route:

```
Route::get('/terms/(:any)', 'PagesController@terms');
```

and the pagesController

```
use App\User;
use App\Role;
use App\Permission;
use App\Item;
use App\tbl_question_category;
use App\subject_title;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class PagesController extends Controller
{


    public function terms($question_category_id)
    {
        return view::make('QuizeBangla.terms')
            ->with('title','Terms & Condition')
            ->with('terms',tbl_question_category::find($question_category_id));
    }
}
```

Model name IS tbl_question_category , here is code

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

```
class tbl_question_category extends Model
{

    protected $table='tbl_question_category';
    public function UserTest(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\UserTest');
    }
}
```

This the code where i want to show data, `terms.blade.php`

```
@extends('QuizeBangla.layouts.app')


@section('content')


@include('TopMenu')

    <section id="page-breadcrumb">
        <div class="vertical-center sun">
             <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="action">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h1 class="title">Terms & Condition</h1>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </section>
    <!--/#action-->

    <section id="map-section">
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table">
                <tr class="success">
                    <td><b>Exams</b></td>
                    <td>Total Question</td>
                    <td>Test Duration</td>
                    <td>Toal Marks</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Click Start</td>
                </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $terms->category_title }}  </td>
                        <td>{{ $terms->number_of_questions }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $terms->test_duration }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $terms->toral_marks }}</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Start</td>
                    </tr>

            </table >
            <div id="gmap"></div>
        </div>
    </section> <!--/#map-section-->

@include('footer')

@endsection
```

when entering my Url for fetching data for id 6 ,`http://localhost:8000/terms/6` it say No page found. could not find where is my silly mistake.

Comment: just use `Route::get('/terms/{id}', 'PagesController@terms');` instead of "(:any)", Laravel route parameters are not type sensitive

Comment: and also remove the forward slash at the beginning of route `Route::get('terms/{id} ', 'PagesController@terms');
`

Comment: Thanks that helps